# Cannot set restype of a function of CDLL: ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

Let's say, that I have a c++ dll. I have a function GET_LAST_MESSAGE, which returns char*. I cannot get the message from it, using python, because python suppose that this function returns long int.

Here is my code:

```
import ctypes
mydll = ctypes.CDLL(libName)
mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE'].argtypes = None
mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE'].restype = ctypes.c_char_p
message = mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']()
```

When i trace this code, I see that the actual state of the variable `mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE'].restype` remains the same (`ctypes.c_long`)

However, the following code works as expected:

```
import ctypes
mydll = ctypes.CDLL(libName)
mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE.argtypes = None
mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
message = mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE()
```

I want to write a class structure for handling cdll, so it is crucial for me to be able to load arbitrary function. That's why I cannot use the second block of code.
Is there any way to specify restype of an arbitrary function?

Comment: `mydll.['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']`? are you sure?

Comment: No, of course not. It should be `mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']`. But the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can still use the "attribute" way while providing a string (you weren't very clear about what is the problem, but I surmise it is because if you have a variable `s="GET_LAST_MESSAGE"`, and not a literal string constant `"GET_LAST_MESSAGE"`, then you could `mydll[s].restype=...` but not `mydll.s.restype=...`)

I wasn't aware of that before your question, but apparently the `["..."]` gives you the original `restype`, and is not altered.
Even if you

```
mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
```

```
mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE'].restype
```

remains unchanged, while `mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE.restype` is

So, let's use the `.` notation while still using a string parameter to specify the attribute name

```
s="GET_LAST_MESSAGE"
mydll.__getattribute__(s).restype = ctypes.c_char_p
```

### Update

My working code (using @MarkTolonen suggestion. It changes nothing. Situations where `getattr(mydll,...)` works are the ones where `mydll.__getattribute__(...)` also works. And when `getattr(mydll,...)` doesn't, `mydll.__getattribute__(...)` doesn't neither. So nothing to do with your problem. Yet, the less `__` you use, the better :D. `getattr` is, indeed, the standard way. It is like calling `str(x)` instead of `x.__str__()`. One is the function, the other the method under the hood.)

```py
fn=getattr(mydll, "GET_LAST_MESSAGE")
# Also works, but `getattr` is better indeed
#fn=mydll.__getattribute__("GET_LAST_MESSAGE")
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
print(fn.restype)
print(fn())
print(fn.restype)
```

My understanding is that there fetching `GET_LAST_MESSAGE` field of mydll "struct" (it is not a struct, but it has a `__getitem__` method — yet another way to access your function) somehow rebuild the `FuncPtr`. So it is not the same `FuncPtr` as the previous one, and it has the default `restype` again

Fetching `.GET_LAST_MESSAGE` field, or `getattr(mydll, GET_LAST_MESSAGE)` or `mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')` returns the attribute that exists. `mydll.__getattr__` creates that attribut, even if it exists.

Hence behavior of this code

```py
print("mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                    ", mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE)
print("mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                    ", mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE)
print("mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']                 ", mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE'])
print("mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']                 ", mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE'])
print("getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')        ", getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')        ", getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')     ", mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')     ", mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')", mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')", mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))

print()

print("mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                    ", mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE)
print("getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')        ", getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')", mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']                 ", mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE'])
print("mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                    ", mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE)
print("getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')        ", getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')", mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')     ", mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                    ", mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE)
print("getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')        ", getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
print("mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')", mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE'))
```

```
mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                     <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86a40>
mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                     <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86a40>
mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']                  <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86b00>
mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']                  <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86bc0>
getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')         <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86a40>
getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')         <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86a40>
mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')      <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86c80>
mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')      <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>
mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE') <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>
mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE') <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>

mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                     <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>
getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')         <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>
mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE') <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>
mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']                  <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86e00>
mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                     <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>
getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')         <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>
mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE') <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86d40>
mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')      <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86ec0>
mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE                     <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86ec0>
getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')         <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86ec0>
mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE') <_FuncPtr object at 0x10df86ec0>
```

As you can see, `mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE`, `getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')` and `mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')` are always the same things. And constant, unless another action reset it.

`mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']` is always a new one. But it doesn't change the value of `mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE` and its synonyms.

And `mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')` is a new one, and it changes the value of `mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE` and its synonyms.

That is consistent with documentations on `getattr`, `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`.

So, the point is

- As long as you get the function once, whatever method you use, and don't reget it a second time, so it is always the same `FuncPtr`, it keeps the same `restype`.

So

```py
fn=mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn() 
fn()
# and any other action, as long as for now on you use `fn` and don't try to re-get it from `mydll`
```

Works

As

```py
fn=mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn()
fn()
```

does

And

```py
fn=getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn()
fn()
```

And

```
fn=mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn()
fn()
```

And

```
fn=mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn()
fn()
```

But, if you re-get the function from `mydll` object, then, not all method works, since some would reset the `FuncPtr` and its `restype`

```py
fn=mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn() 
mydll['GET_LAST_MESSAGE']() # not working
```

wouldn't work

Nor would

```
fn=mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn() 
mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')() # not working
```

But

```
fn=mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn() 
mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE() # working
```

would work

As

```
fn=mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn() 
mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')() # working
```

And

```
fn=getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')
fn.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn() 
getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')() # working
```

Or even combinations of those.
Like

```
fn=mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE
getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE`).restype=ctypes.c_char_p
fn() 
mydll.__getattribute__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')() # working
```

So

### tl;dr

- If you get once for all `GET_LAST_MESSAGE` from `mydll` with whatever method you like, (including your first, `[...]`), and store it once for all somewhere, and then only works from the place (variable, array, dict, ...) where you kept it, then, it would work with any method
- If you plan to refetch it several times from `mydll`, then, `getattr` is the way to go (basically, it does the same thing: it fetch it once, and the subsequent calls it just return the one it fetched the first time)

Comment: Wow, that worked, thank you! But unfortunately, the error not gone...  For some strange reason, i cannot call my function using `__getattr__`. It still returns long int. The function only returns char*, if I call it like `mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE()`. Moreover, if i write the line `ans1 = mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')()` and then (on the next line) `ans2 = mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE()`, both ans1 and ans2 has int type!

Comment: The most curious to me is that i does not observe such a strange behavior with argstype. I can define argstype any of these 3 ways.

Comment: If i write it in reverse order (`ans2 = mydll.GET_LAST_MESSAGE()` and then `ans1 = mydll.__getattr__('GET_LAST_MESSAGE')()`), `ans2` has the type 'bytes' and ans1 has the type 'int'.

Comment: FYI: `getattr(mydll, 'GET_LAST_MESSAGE')`

Comment: On my machine, it is only when mixing different methods that I get such behavior. See updated code

Comment: @MarkTolonen, WOW! That worked! Could you please explain, what dark magic hides behind these symbols? Why `getattr(dll, func_name)` works, while `dll.__getattr__(func_name)` not working?

Comment: @Victor `__getattribute__` is called unconditionally to look up attributes in an object with either `gettattr(obj, 'func')` or simply `obj.func`.  If the attribute is not found then `__getattr__` is called.  Without looking at `ctypes` code, I'd say that its `__getattr__` implementation always returns a **new** object, while `__getattribute__` calls `__getattr__` and caches it, so later calls retrieve the same object.  `getattr` is the correct way to retrieve dynamic attributes.